SDK Manager Error: 'Errors during XML parse' on Linux (Lubuntu and Kali) - How to Fix?
I've been facing an issue after installing the cmdline-tools on Linux (Lubuntu). I added the path correctly, but when I type the following command in the terminal:
bash
sdkmanager --list

I get the following errors:
Warning: Errors during XML parse:                                               
Warning: Additionally, the fallback loader failed to parse the XML.

I've tried everything, including updating the network drivers, using different networks, and updating the SDK, but nothing seems to work.
It's worth mentioning that I also tried the same command on a different Linux distribution (Kali), and I encountered the same errors.
Does anyone know how to solve this?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I simply installed the cmdline-tools executable for Linux from the Android Studio site, extracted it, and added the environment variables on both Lubuntu and Kali. The sdkmanager --version command is recognized, but the sdkmanager --list command gives the XML-related errors I mentioned:
Warning: Errors during XML parse:
Warning: Additionally, the fallback loader failed to parse the XML
I really don't know how to solve this.

I've seen this on MacOS as well. Not sure when it first appeared. It doesn't appear to affect functionality, though, as far as I can tell:
➜ sdkmanager --version           
16.0

➜ sdkmanager --list   
Warning: Errors during XML parse:                                               
Warning: Additionally, the fallback loader failed to parse the XML.             
[=======================================] 100% Computing updates...             
Installed packages:
  Path                                                  | Version       | Description                                     | Location                                             
  -------                                               | -------       | -------                                         | -------                                              
  build-tools;34.0.0                                    | 34.0.0        | Android SDK Build-Tools 34                      | build-tools/34.0.0                                   
  build-tools;35.0.0                                    | 35.0.0        | Android SDK Build-Tools 35                      | build-tools/35.0.0                                   
  cmdline-tools;latest                                  | 16.0          | Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest)         | cmdline-tools/latest 

Not sure if it's related, but I also noted that on in the SDK Manager tool in Android Studio that on the SDK Update Sites tab, the Android Automotive multi-window System Images row has an error icon (see screenshot). I don't know of a way to change or fix it, though. ¯_(ツ)_/¯

